# Trying to find diff between two lists, and appending the diff into third list, my third list is resulting nested form in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists, difference

When I am coding on my local with limited values in the lists it is working and no nested list has been created. But when I run the code with my main code, the difference list(third list) appears in nested form.

```
def non_match_elements(first_list, second_list):
        third_list = []
        for item in first_list:
            if item not in second_list:
                third_list.append(item)
def main():
    first_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,15,22]
    second_list = [2,3,4,14,18]
    third_list = (non_match_elements(first_list, second_list))
    print(third_list))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code runs fine, but when my original lists come into picture it results the third list as nested list. How can I figure out what is wrong? My orignal lists have lots of elements in string form and both are non-nested lists. And the data of those lists comes from different functions

Comment: Without seeing your "original lists", we have no way of being able to help

Comment: ["Something.1.0.00643-NEW", "Something.1.0.00654-NEW", "Something.1.0.00671-NEW", "Something.1.0.00687-NEW", "Something.1.0.00718-NEW", "Something.1.0.00737-NEW", "Something.1.0.00747-NEW", "Something.1.0.00758-NEW", "Something.1.0.00774-NEW", "Something.1.0.00777-NEW", "Something.1.0.00799-NEW", "Something.1.0.00814-NEW", "Something.1.0.00821-NEW", "Something.1.0.00843-NEW", "Something.1.0.00855-NEW", "Something.1.0.00867-NEW", "Something.1.0.00886-NEW", "Something.1.0.00900-NEW", "Something.1.0.00920-NEW", "Something.1.0.00925-NEW", "Something.1.0.00942-NEW", "Something.1.0.00955-NEW"]

Comment: it goes like this for the other list as well @inspectorG4dget

Comment: tried that list, with extra list that is part of this list. and worked fine with my answer below

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.

Comment: Have you tried `third_list.extend()` rather than `append()`?  Additionally, do the lists have duplicate values, or are the values in each list unique in that list?

Comment: @S3DEV I did, I realised my first list was in nested form and I was printing it way before it was being nested. and yes .extend() would have helped too, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of typos in example:

- `third_list = (non_match_elements(first_list, second_list))` - unnecessary parenthesis
- `print(third_list))` - extra `)`
- did not return the `third_list` from function

Curious how come that it worked for you?

After modifications - works fine for me:

```
def non_match_elements(first_list, second_list):
    third_list = []
    for item in first_list:
        if item not in second_list:
            third_list.append(item)
    return third_list
            

first_list = ["Something.1.0.00643-NEW", "Something.1.0.00654-NEW", "Something.1.0.00671-NEW", "Something.1.0.00687-NEW", "Something.1.0.00718-NEW", "Something.1.0.00737-NEW", "Something.1.0.00747-NEW", "Something.1.0.00758-NEW", "Something.1.0.00774-NEW", "Something.1.0.00777-NEW", "Something.1.0.00799-NEW", "Something.1.0.00814-NEW", "Something.1.0.00821-NEW", "Something.1.0.00843-NEW", "Something.1.0.00855-NEW", "Something.1.0.00867-NEW", "Something.1.0.00886-NEW", "Something.1.0.00900-NEW", "Something.1.0.00920-NEW", "Something.1.0.00925-NEW", "Something.1.0.00942-NEW"]
second_list = []
third_list = non_match_elements(first_list, second_list)
print(third_list)
print(first_list==third_list)
```

output:

```
['Something.1.0.00643-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00654-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00671-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00687-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00718-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00737-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00747-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00758-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00774-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00777-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00799-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00814-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00821-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00843-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00855-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00867-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00886-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00900-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00920-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00925-NEW', 'Something.1.0.00942-NEW']
True
```

because all the items in first_list are not in second_list - all of them printed out, I also printed out the check if first_list == third_list. don't see any problem.

Comment: kindly ignore the typos, it was my bad. when I re-typed here it got missed. this one is working fine, but as I mentioned its not working with my original lists, which are being fetched from other functions. My main looks like this :

def main():
first_list = []
second_list = []
first_list.append(calling my function here)
second_list.append(calling my second function here)
third_list = (non_match_elements(first_list, second_list))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Comment: can you provide both lists in your question please? I'll try to check your specific lists

Comment: first_list = ["Something.1.0.00643-NEW", "Something.1.0.00654-NEW", "Something.1.0.00671-NEW", "Something.1.0.00687-NEW", "Something.1.0.00718-NEW", "Something.1.0.00737-NEW", "Something.1.0.00747-NEW", "Something.1.0.00758-NEW", "Something.1.0.00774-NEW", "Something.1.0.00777-NEW", "Something.1.0.00799-NEW", "Something.1.0.00814-NEW", "Something.1.0.00821-NEW", "Something.1.0.00843-NEW", "Something.1.0.00855-NEW", "Something.1.0.00867-NEW", "Something.1.0.00886-NEW", "Something.1.0.00900-NEW", "Something.1.0.00920-NEW", "Something.1.0.00925-NEW", "Something.1.0.00942-NEW"]  & second_list =[ ]

Comment: I have taken second list empty for a while to save some time on testing

Comment: I have taken second list empty for a while to save some time on testing